# Como adicionar elementos de uma lista em um dicionário em Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista, dicionário

Boa tarde, estou com problema para adicionar elementos de uma lista em um dicionário.

Os elementos da lista para colocar no dicionário são:

```
['Joao', '83889023', 'Maria', '81944356', 'Marcos', '32258899', 'Ana', '88235423', 'George', '1254345', 'Rafaela', '8899345671', 'Pedro', '83223345', 'Aline', '842234565', 'Carlos', '83554463', 'Julia', '13565446', 'Murilo', '23543646', 'Mayra', '233253425', 'Italo', '842142543', 'Rita', '3253464457', 'Aldo', '77443456', 'Raquel', '8384423553', 'Henrique', '88342235', 'Joyce', '987676342', 'Daniel', '3253456346', 'Livia', '325346634', 'Pablo', '87461723', 'Carla', '87351236']
```

O problema é: No dicionário a **chave terá que ser o número** e o **valor terá que ser o nome.**

O que eu tentei foi:

```
dic = {}
x = 0
y = 0
for elem in dados:
    dic[elem] = dados[y]
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
print(dic)
```

Porém o que eu recebo é:

```
{'Joao': 'Joao', '83889023': '83889023', 'Maria': 'Maria', '81944356': '81944356', 'Marcos': 'Marcos', '32258899': '32258899', 'Ana': 'Ana', '88235423': '88235423', 'George': 'George', '1254345': '1254345', 'Rafaela': 'Rafaela', '8899345671': '8899345671', 'Pedro': 'Pedro', '83223345': '83223345', 'Aline': 'Aline', '842234565': '842234565', 'Carlos': 'Carlos', '83554463': '83554463', 'Julia': 'Julia', '13565446': '13565446', 'Murilo': 'Murilo', '23543646': '23543646', 'Mayra': 'Mayra', '233253425': '233253425', 'Italo': 'Italo', '842142543': '842142543', 'Rita': 'Rita', '3253464457': '3253464457', 'Aldo': 'Aldo', '77443456': '77443456', 'Raquel': 'Raquel', '8384423553': '8384423553', 'Henrique': 'Henrique', '88342235': '88342235', 'Joyce': 'Joyce', '987676342': '987676342', 'Daniel': 'Daniel', '3253456346': '3253456346', 'Livia': 'Livia', '325346634': '325346634', 'Pablo': 'Pablo', '87461723': '87461723', 'Carla': 'Carla', '87351236': '87351236'}
```

Como resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 5):

O seu código gera um resultado errado porque o valor de `y` sempre coincidirá com o índice de `elem` na lista e, desta forma, sempre serão o mesmo valor. Para implementar algo deste gênero, você precisa percorrer a lista a cada dois elementos:

```
dic = {}
y = 1
for elem in dados[::2]:
    dic[dados[y]] = elem
    y = y + 2
print(dic)
```

Mas uma solução mais simples é apresentada abaixo.

---

O Python possui uma recomendação da implementação da função `pairwise` baseada na função [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Porém, veja que o segundo elemento do primeiro par será o primeiro elemento no segundo par e não é isso que precisamos. Isto acontece pois `a` e `b` são iteradores diferentes. Ao fazermos ser o mesmo iterador, teremos a saída desejada:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    it = iter(iterable)
    return zip(it, it)
```

Desta forma, basta fazermos:

```
name_map = {number: name for name, number in pairwise(data)}
```

Para obter o resultado:

```
{
    '83889023': 'Joao', 
    '81944356': 'Maria', 
    '32258899': 'Marcos', 
    '88235423': 'Ana', 
    '1254345': 'George', 
    '8899345671': 'Rafaela', 
    '83223345': 'Pedro', 
    '842234565': 'Aline', 
    '83554463': 'Carlos', 
    '13565446': 'Julia', 
    '23543646': 'Murilo', 
    '233253425': 'Mayra', 
    '842142543': 'Italo', 
    '3253464457': 'Rita', 
    '77443456': 'Aldo', 
    '8384423553': 'Raquel', 
    '88342235': 'Henrique', 
    '987676342': 'Joyce', 
    '3253456346': 'Daniel', 
    '325346634': 'Livia', 
    '87461723': 'Pablo', 
    '87351236': 'Carla'
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FavoriteColdCondition) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/jxMeiX) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/0e9a0c64d226bce14461a6483117e7ca)</sup>